# SNMP v1 - Agent IP

Tags: snmp

I'm sending SNMP traps using Net-SNMP utils (5.3). I'm setting the agent to a valid server IP but the NMS is receiving the trap as if it was a trap for the server generating it and not for the other server that I'm using in the agent field . I'm totally confused as to why this would be happening, other servers are using the same package and it works fine!

Thanks,
PJ

Comment: Could you show us an example? What command line arguments are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Can you capture wireshark log to see if the IP address in SNMP level TRAP message is the same as the sender IP address in IP level?